# Probability of passing a series of tests

Tags: probability

A product is subjected to four different tests. The probability that the product under test fails that test is $1\%,3\%,2\%$ and $1\%$, respectively.

The probability that a product under test fails one of these is

$1-(1-0.01)(1-0.03)(1-0.02)(1-0.1) = 7\% $

But I don't quite understand why I should calculate it in this manner?

Comment: Because what you wrote is the complementary probability of passing of all test. And the complementary probability is just failing at least one test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability $$(1-0.01)(1-0.03)(1-0.02)(1-0.01)$$ gives the probability of passing all of the tests.

Generally, $1 - P(A)$ gives the probability of $P(A)$ NOT happening, so $$1 - (1-0.01)(1-0.03)(1-0.02)(1-0.01)$$ gives the probability of not passing all tests, or in other words, failing at least one.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is:

> What is the probability that a product, under those tests, will fail.

So if it fails ANY of those test - the product is a failure. It can fail under test 1, 2, 3 or 4. So if you look at the question differently you can ask - *when will the product be considered a success?* and the answer is: *it passes test 1,2,3 & 4.*

so **(1−0.01)(1−0.03)(1−0.02)(1−0.01)** will give you the success probability (it will pass test 1 AND test 2 AND test 3 AND test 4) and **1-success probability** will give you the probability of failure.